# How to set a default avatar in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a default avatar for my page but only a string appear, not my image. Here's what I do:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar')->default('/storage/avatars/avatar.png');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

in Migrations
-------------------
 <img src="{{ $page.props.auth.user.avatar }}" alt=""> {{ $page.props.auth.user.avatar }}

In my code
obs: this second {{ $page.props.auth.user.avatar }} is only for show what is coming
```

And that's my directorys
[image]

Comment: `$page.props.auth.user.avatar` is not valid PHP code.

Comment: I'm using Laravel Breeze with Vue and my username appear with $page.props.auth.user.name

Comment: Ok, not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this to the footer of your site

```
<script>
    window.user = '{{ auth()->user() }}'
</script>
```

Then you will be able to access your users attributes in vue. like this:

```
window.user.avatar
```

**Edit:**
after reading comments; did you make sure to add

```
protected $fillable = ['name','avatar'];
protected $appends = ['avatar'];
```

in your model. all models should have either

`protected $fillable = []`
(add model attributed to the array that you would like to be able to save directly from your controller, i.e. `'name', 'age', 'gender'` etc) or

`protected $guarded = []`
(add attributes you would NOT want editable i.e. `'password', 'token'` etc) read more about [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) in the docs.
and

```
 public function getAvatarAttribute($value)
 {
 return $this->avatar = $value
 }
```

to your model.

Appends with add the return value of the `function get_______Attribute()` in snake case, to json when u send your model to the frontend. [check it out in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Comment: Where i put this function and this protected?

Comment: in your model. all models should have either `protected $fillable = []` (add model attributed to the array that you would like to be able to save directly from your controller, i.e. 'name', 'age', 'gender' etc) or `protected $guarded = []`  (add attributes you would NOT want editable i.e. 'password', 'token' etc) [read more about mass assignment in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: and appends with add the return value of the `function get_______Attribute()` in snake case, to json when u send your model to the frontend. [check it out in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)